# Facebook permissions - Android Mobile app

Tags: java, android, facebook, permissions

I am trying to retrieve the info of Facebook user in my android app

This is what I got so far:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.firstandroidapp;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest;
import com.facebook.model.*;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private MainFragment mainFragment;

//   


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
            .commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }
    }

      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
}
```

and the MainFragment.java

```
package com.firstandroidapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.facebook.LoggingBehavior;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.Settings;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphObject;
import com.facebook.model.GraphObjectList;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private TextView userInfoTextView;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        userInfoTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userInfoTextView);
        authButton.setFragment(this);

        List<String> permission=new ArrayList<String>();
        permission.add("public_profile");
        permission.add("email");
        permission.add("user_birthday");
        permission.add("user_location");

        permission.add("user_likes");
        permission.add("user_interests");
        permission.add("user_relationships");

        authButton.setReadPermissions(permission);




        return view;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Request user data and show the results
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {



                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    userInfoTextView.setText(buildUserInfoDisplay(user));
                }
            });
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
            userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
     // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
               (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private interface MyGraphLanguage extends GraphObject {
        // Getter for the ID field
        String getId();
        // Getter for the Name field
        String getName();
    }


    private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {
        StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");
        //Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);

        // Example: typed access (name)
        // - no special permissions required
        userInfo.append(String.format("Name: %s\n\n", 
            user.getName()));


        // Example: typed access (birthday)
        // - requires user_birthday permission

//      userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n", 
//              user.getBirthday()));
//      
        userInfo.append(String.format("E-mail: %s\n\n", 
                user.asMap().get("email").toString()));

        // Example: partially typed access, to location field,
        // name key (location)
        // - requires user_location permission
//      userInfo.append(String.format("Location: %s\n\n", 
//          user.getLocation().getProperty("name")));

        // Example: access via property name (locale)
        // - no special permissions required
        userInfo.append(String.format("Locale: %s\n\n", 
            user.getProperty("locale")));

        // Example: access via key for array (languages) 
        // - requires user_likes permission
//      JSONArray languages = (JSONArray)user.getProperty("languages");
//      if (languages.length() > 0) {
//          ArrayList<String> languageNames = new ArrayList<String> ();
//
//          // Get the data from creating a typed interface
//          // for the language data.
//          GraphObjectList<MyGraphLanguage> graphObjectLanguages = 
//              GraphObject.Factory.createList(languages, 
//                                             MyGraphLanguage.class);
//
//          // Iterate through the list of languages
//          for (MyGraphLanguage language : graphObjectLanguages) {
//              // Add the language name to a list. Use the name
//              // getter method to get access to the name field.
//              languageNames.add(language.getName());
//          } 
//
//          userInfo.append(String.format("Languages: %s\n\n", 
//          languageNames.toString()));
//      }   


        Log.d(TAG, user.getName() + user.asMap().get("email").toString() + user.getProperty("locale") );
        return userInfo.toString();
    }

}
```

and I only get he Name and e-mail and language and I want more information such as the birthday and pages he/she likes and already added these permissions but for example the birthday returns null any idea what I am doing wrong please ??

Any help would be appreciate it 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure if the birthday date exists on Facebook profile as well? or they may have set to privacy.